# how to get Json format from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

hi i want to convert my array in json format and my current array in this struncture that u cann see below, as well as i am showing structure that i want using javascript.

**current Array Format:

```
Array[0]
abc: Array[1]
0: "English"
length: 1
abc1: Array[2]
0: "English"
1: "Urdu"
length: 2
```

**strong text** i Want json format from current Array Format:**

```
[
    {
        "abc": [
            {
                "0": "English"
            },
            {
                "1": "Urdu"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `JSON.stringify(myArray)`.

Documentation: http://www.json.org/js.html

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/5GzsH/)